# Android Search In ListView And Jump To Particular Search Result

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way we can jump/scroll to the particular message when user click on the search button. (As attached).

For example there is more than 1 message with the word "melaka" in the chat screen. How do we determine the position of the particular message when the item is not yet visible in the ListView and scroll to the particular message. Is there a way to scroll to the particular message and highlight the message based on the Column ID in the database? Please advice. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    searchtext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                       // When user changed the Text
                   CategoryKart.this.yourlistview.getFilter().filter(youtarraylist);
         }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                                  int arg3) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
   });
```